# How do I restore a Dragon Age 2 save file?

Tags: dragon-age-2, windows

I reformatted my PC and ended up with a backup of my Dragon Age 2 files not getting recognized by my new Dragon Age 2 installation. I basically just copied it into the `Documents\Bioware\Dragon Age 2` folder. Anyone know if there are anymore steps I need to do so that my saves get restored to their former glory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you copied your character folders then it should be a matter of putting those same folders back into the Dragon Age 2 save directory as you found them.  Remember to also download all the necessary updates for the game.

Reference: http://www.gamespot.com/dragon-age-ii/forum/can-i-transfer-a-saved-game-played-on-one-pc-to-another-58410232